# AceEditor setValue() not triggering my React App's onChange function

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I am using Cypress.io to do testing on my React App. I'm using Ace Editor in one of my components. I'm using an onChange function to set the value of a variable according to the value/data of the Ace Editor, that way I can validate if the user entered something in to the Editor.

The problem that I'm facing is that when I do a editor.setValue then it doesn't trigger my onChange function so it is not setting the value of the variable and then validation fails.

Here is the test where I set the value/data of the Ace Editor.

```
it("Enter Template Data", () => {
 window.cy.get('#aceEditor').then((ele) => {
   const editor = ace.edit(ele[0]);
   editor.setValue("Some Text");
 });
});
```

I set a variable called data with the data of the Ace Editor which normally works when I manually enter data in the Ace Editor but doesn't work when I set the value using "editor.setValue".

How can I enter data in the Ace Editor using Cypress that also triggers my onChange function in my Component?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cy.trigger()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger.html#Syntax) to manually dispatch a DOM event on an element.

Assuming that `#aceEditor` is the element which should be sending the `onChange`, you can just tag it on at the end:

```js
it("Enter Template Data", () => {
  cy.get('#aceEditor')
  .then((ele) => {
    const editor = ace.edit(ele[0]);
    editor.setValue("Some Text");
  })
 .trigger('change') // `cy.then()` yields the previous subject if nothing is returned,
                    // so we can just chain this on to the end
});
```

Comment: It does not work, thank you anyway. I'm not sure why but it still doesn't trigger my onChange function.

Comment: @Arrie_CyberGuy can you share the app code that listens for the onchange event, and where it's attached to the aceeditor?

Comment: sorry, where is this ace variable coming from? `ace.edit`?